# How to change the Wolfram Alpha query timeout for Ctrl+=?

Tags: wolfram-alpha-queries

Sometimes retrieving results from Wolfram Alpha takes time and the default query timeout is not sufficient.

For engagement with Wolfram Alpha implicitly for `expr` containing `Units` or `Entities` one can use the following wrapper to temporarily control the time out:

```
ClearAll[wolframAlphaQuery];

wolframAlphaQuery[time_][expr_]:=Block[{
    WolframAlphaClient`Private`$AlphaQueryTimeConstraint=time
},
    expr
];
```

But for <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>=</kbd> interpretation this is not applicable and sometimes these queries result in `Timed out while parsing. Click to retry.`:

> Failure["TimedOut",  Association[  "MessageTemplate" -> "A network
>   operation timed out. Please try again later.", "MessageParameters"
>   -> Association[],    "Query" -> ...]]

What is the way to change the timeout for this?

`WolframAlpha[...]` is a programmatic way to access <kbd>=</kbd>+<kbd>=</kbd>+<kbd>=</kbd> but what is the equivalent for <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>=</kbd> (Inline Free-form Input)?