# What is the current WolframAlpha server capacity?

Tags: wolfram-alpha-queries

Considering the increasing workload WolframAlpha is now receiving as it is getting more tightly integrated into the Wolfram language. With things like `Entities` even people who don't rely on free-form input (inline <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>=</kbd> and entire cell <kbd>=</kbd>+<kbd>=</kbd>) or raw WolframAlpha (<kbd>=</kbd>+<kbd>=</kbd>+<kbd>=</kbd>) or other interpretation interfaces (like now `WolframAlpha Notebooks` and `Cloud hosted Notebooks`), even the average Wolfram language user can't avoid WolframAlpha in their interaction with the language.

So my question is, all this must be increasing the number of queries WolframAlpha receives every day. So can anyone here shed some light on where does the server capacity stands? How much is the current utilization? What is the average queries per day and from what sources like `Entities` or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>=</kbd> or <kbd>=</kbd>+<kbd>=</kbd>+<kbd>=</kbd>. [Should we expect to see more timeouts or delayed responses when querying WolframAlpha](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/215518/how-to-change-the-wolfram-alpha-query-timeout-for-ctrl))? And how often are live databases behind builtin `Entities` updated (excluding things like `Financial` which are of course update daily or should be!), like `FoodType` (which seems to be down right now at the time of posting this, try: `RandomEntity["FoodType",5]` or `Entity["FoodType", "Acerola"]["Image"]`).